# PHP regex find and replace in text and numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, text-processing

I have input in that format:

Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.

I want replace this to here with PHP:

GPS:12.3456,78.9012:
   Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.

So, again, the input in big text:

"

Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla...
Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.
And more text...

"

This output needed:

"

Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla...
GPS:12.3456,78.9012:
Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.
And more text...

"

Output need to append this BEFORE what I searching:
"`GPS:12.3456,78.9012:`"

The 2 numbers also in all line different: 12.3456 and 78.9012
All others are fixed. (Spaces, other characters.)

If you just now how to detect and get this line from big text:
"`Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.`"
Also helps.
If I have this line, I can find numbers and replace.
I will use explode to detect numbers (finding space before and ° after the number) and str_replace to replace the input to output. I know not this is the best way but I know that functions.

(Sorry, text formatting not working as I want. I fixed the input, output, changed "," to space)

Thanks!

Comment: ok use preg_match to extract the numbers. but can there be other numbers in there? can we assume the number we are extracting is always in ###.#### format?

Comment: Number format: 1-2 number . 1-4 number. 1.1, 22.1, 1.22, 1.333, 1.4444 or also 22.4444 can be. I need the input numbers, then needed to generate append text ("GPS:number1,number2:"), then replace the input with added output (add GPS before the input text line).

Comment: Web.Guard and Pé de Leão code works berfectly, both are great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°. And more text...  ';

echo preg_replace('%([\w\s,]+:\s(\d+\.\d+)°,\s[\w\s,]+:\s(\d+\.\d+)°)%ui', ' GPS:$2,$3: $1', $text);



//Output: Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... GPS:12.3456,78.9012: Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°. And more text...
```

Comment: This works perfectly with changed text also. Great! You are also the best! Thank you! :)

Comment: Is "Text,number<?>" always fixed?

Comment: Fixed, but no numbers, just 2 different text with foreign characters, like éá, but it's excellent, working! You are great! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but I'm late for dinner!

```
<?
$text = 'Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla...
Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°.
And more text...';

$lines = array();
foreach(explode("\r\n",$text) as $line){
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\d{0,3}\.?\d{0,20}°/', $line, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
        $match[] = $result[0][$i];
    }
    if(count($match)>0){
        $lines[] = 'GPS:'.str_replace('°','',implode(',',$match));
    }
    $lines[] = $line;

}
echo implode('<br>',$lines);
?>

Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla...
GPS:12.3456,78.9012
Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°.
And more text...
```

Comment: It's near excellent but my output is this: ---- 


GPS:12.3456,78.9012
Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°. And more text...

---- so not inserting the new text BEFORE the Text,number1 place, just the all text start place.

Comment: So it's all on one line? Are there multiple GPS coordinates on this single line?

Comment: Yes, all in 1 line, the input line: "Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°. And more text..." And output line needed: "Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... GPS:12.3456,78.9012: Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°. And more text..." You can see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla...
Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.
And more text';
$pattern = '#[a-zá-úàü\d ,]+:\s?([\d.]+)°[^:]+:\s?([\d.]+)°#i';
return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) {
    return sprintf("GPS:%s,%s:\n%s.",
        $match[1],
        $match[2],
        $match[0]
    );
}, $text);
```

Comment: This output: "Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... Text,number1: GPS:12.3456,78.9012: Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°.. And more text" ---- Needed "GPS:12.3456,78.9012:" BEFORE "Text,number1:" text.

Comment: You are the fastest and BEST, but I sadly I made mistake. Not this the line: "Text,number1: 12.3456°, text,number2: 78.9012°." This: "Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°.". No "," just a space separator in words. I now update the texts. Sorry, It's my fault.

Comment: Still not working but also it's my fault because in input no numbers (I added for example), so not this the exact output: "Text number1: 12.3456°, text number2: 78.9012°" This: "Text abcdég: 47.9667°, Text áécde: 19.8333°." So, no number before the 2 number, just alphabets with accent, like á, é character, like "Text abcdég: 47.9667°, Text áécde: 19.8333°." Now the output is this: "Bla bla bla, random text, bla bla... Text abcdé!!mxcmgps::47.9667,19.8333!! g: 47.9667°, Text áécde: 19.8333°.. And more text"

Comment: @FallenAngel - New update with accents. Hope I understood correctly.